# Beautiful Soup - How can I scrape images that contain a specific src attribute?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've just started learning webscraping a few days ago and thought it would be fun to try scraping Mangadex as a mini project. Thank you for the advice in advance!

I'm trying to scrape images by extracting the src attribute of an img tag using Beautiful Soup 4 and Python 3.7

The HTML section I'm interested in is:

```
<div class="reader-image-wrapper col-auto my-auto justify-content-center align-items-center noselect nodrag row no-gutters" data-state="2" data-page="1" style="order: 1;">
  <img draggable="false" class="noselect nodrag cursor-pointer" src="https://s5.mangadex.org/data/554c97a14357f3972912e08817db4a03/x1.jpg">
</div>
```

Each image that I'm interested in contains a src attribute that begins with "https://s5.mangadex.org/data/" so I thought maybe I could target images that begin with that specific attribute.

I've tried using select() to find the img element and then using get() to find the src but didn't have any luck with that specific html section.

HTML sections that did work using select() and get() were:

```
<img class="mx-2" height="38px" src="/images/misc/navbar.svg?3" alt="MangaDex" title="MangaDex">

<img src="/images/misc/miku.jpg" width="100%">

<img class="mx-2" height="38px" src="/images/misc/navbar.svg?3" alt="MangaDex" title="MangaDex">
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

**attrs** will list all the attributes set in that tag. Its a dictionary so to get specific attribute value see below.

```
# for getting webpages
import requests
r = requests.get(URL_LINK)

base_url='https://s5.mangadex.org/data/'
# for beautiful soup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
imgs = bs.findAll('img')
for img in imgs:
    src = img.attrs['src']
    if not src.startswith(base_url):
        src = base_url+src
    print(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
      <div class="reader-image-wrapper col-auto my-auto justify-content-center align-items-center noselect nodrag row no-gutters" data-state="2" data-page="1" style="order: 1;">
      <img draggable="false" class="noselect nodrag cursor-pointer" src="https://s5.mangadex.org/data/554c97a14357f3972912e08817db4a03/x1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="reader-image-wrapper col-auto my-auto justify-content-center align-items-center noselect nodrag row no-gutters" data-state="2" data-page="1" style="order: 1;">
      <img draggable="false" class="noselect nodrag cursor-pointer" src="https://s4.mangadex.org/data/554c97a14357f3972912e08817db4a03/x1.jpg">
      </div>
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for n in soup.find_all('img'):    
    if(n.get('src').startswith( 'https://s5.mangadex.org/data/')):
      print(n.get('src'))
```

result:

```
https://s5.mangadex.org/data/554c97a14357f3972912e08817db4a03/x1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **scrape** mangadex with BeautifulSoup **DIRECTLY**. Mangadex load their images with javascript after the document is ready. What you get with BeautifulSoup is that empty document. That is why it is failing. This website explains how you can **scrape** web pages that rely on javascript to serve their content:

https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap